Strategy Backtesting Help: Imported Indicator Values in Strategy Not Updating Historically
I'm developing a strategy that imports numerical values (1, -1, or 0) from a separate indicator to represent market regimes (e.g., Bullish, Bearish, Neutral).
These values are then converted to boolean flags in my strategy.
So basically indicator plot export, --> to source imports in strategy.
However, I'm struggling to achieve accurate deep back testing. The regime flags seem not to reflect the actual historical state throughout the back test. As if the deep / backtester takes the strategy back but not the indicator values.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong or if it is possible at all to use, and back test with indicator on strategy?
I've attempted to address this using barstate.ishistory to update the flags only when back testing historical data, but the issue persists.
This is the code from the export indicator:
indicator("Regime Signal Exporter", overlay=true)

// Example conditions for regime detection
bool bullishCondition = close > open[1]   
bool bearishCondition = close < open[1]  

// Regime flags
var bool isBullish = false
var bool isBearish = false

// Update regime flags based on conditions (mutual exclusivity)
if bullishCondition
    isBullish  := true
    isBearish  := false
else 
    isBullish := false 
if bearishCondition 
    isBearish  := true
    isBullish  := false
else
    isBearish := false

// Numerical values for export
exportBullRegime   = isBullish ?  1 : 0 
exportBearRegime   = isBearish ? -1 : 0

plot(exportBullRegime,  title="Mr. Bull", style=plot.style_line, display=display.none)
plot(exportBearRegime,  title="Mr. Bear", style=plot.style_line, display=display.none) 

And here is how I import in into the strategy:
strategy("Regime imports", overlay=true)

// Input source

imported_BullRegime  = input.source(title="Mr. Bull", group="Market Regime Imports", defval=close)  

imported_BearRegime  = input.source(title="Mr. Bear", group="Market Regime Imports", defval=close) 

// Market Regime Variables
bool isBull  = false
bool isBear  = false

if barstate.ishistory  
    if imported_BullRegime == 1
        isBull := true       
        isBear := false     
    else if imported_BearRegime == -1
        isBear := true      
        isBull := false      
    else  // Neither regime is active, reset the flags
        isBull := false
        isBear := false


Thank you for your time and help !

you can export a single plot, with two values
something like that:
// Numerical values for export
exportRegime = isBullish ?  1 : isBearish ? -1 : 0

plot(exportRegime, 'exportRegime' , editable = false, display = display.data_window)

and
// Input source
imported_Regime  = input.source(title="Mr. Bull", group="Market Regime Imports", defval=close)  

// Market Regime Variables
bool isBull  = false
bool isBear  = false

if barstate.ishistory  
    if imported_Regime == 1
        isBull := true       
        isBear := false     
    else if imported_Regime == -1
        isBear := true      
        isBull := false      
    else  // Neither regime is active, reset the flags
        isBull := false
        isBear := false


Yes that is true, and good call! But could this be the reason the back tester does not reflect the decisions based on these values, as they are reflected on the visible chart but not when the back tester is used.
